# Why does Result::map_err behave differently when using ? or return

Tags: rust

I've been writing some error handling code, and I've noticed this interesting behavior when handling errors in different positions.

```rs
use std::io;

fn into_test() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let res: Result<(), ()> = Ok(());

    // adding .into() will cause an error
    res.map_err(|_| io::ErrorKind::Other)?;

    // not having .into() will cause an error
    res.map_err(|_| io::ErrorKind::Other.into())
}
```

Why does this happen? Is it unique to `std::io::ErrorKind`/`Error`?

Comment: The `?` mark operator automatically calls `.into()` on the error. Adding it manually doesn't work, because then it'd be called twice and Rust can't figure out what the intermediate type should be. On the other hand, when you're returning the result from the function the types must match, so you have to call `.into()` .

Comment: @isaactfa Close -- it actually calls `From::from(err)`, it does not use `Into` for conversion. It seems like a subtle difference but it means [`Into` bounds do not work in a generic context](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f798e46d9161c4e3c5cb3a9b50de0fd6), even though usually that's the preferred bound -- you have to bound on `From`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` operator takes a [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) type, including `Result` and `Option` and a handful of other types, and:

- if it is ok-ish, unwraps and yields the ok value
- if it is error-ish, calls `From::from` on the error to convert it to the appropriate type (whatever the return type of the current function is), then returns from the current function with that value.

The key here is the `From::from` part. For this to work, the error-ish value must be an `A` such that `E: From<A>` if the function returns a `Result<T, E>` (or more generally, if the function returns a `Try<Output=T, Residual=E>`). Converting errors to other errors is handy — it saves you from having to write `.map_err(From::from)` yourself — but can lead to type ambiguities if used in cases where the input or outputs are not known. The underlying principle here is that when Rust attempts to infer and unify the types of expressions, there must be exactly one way to do it.

---

```rust
// adding .into() will cause an error
res.map_err(|_| io::ErrorKind::Other)?;
```

What type should `ErrorKind::Other.into()` be? All we know about it is that it must be an `E` such that `io::Error: From<E>` (since a [`io::Result<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html) is a [`Result<T, io::Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html)). But this could be any number of types — `E` is not limited to merely `io::Error` itself. By adding `into()`, you've introduced an ambiguity into type resolution.

---

```rust
// not having .into() will cause an error
res.map_err(|_| io::ErrorKind::Other.into())
```

This is the last expression of the function, which means it's the function's return value, and so it must have the function's return type. Accordingly, the error variant must have type `io::Error`. If you wrote only `io::ErrorKind::Other`, Rust would see that `io::ErrorKind` is not an `io::Error` and give a type error. But `io::ErrorKind` is `Into<io::Error>`, so when you write `io::ErrorKind::Other.into()`, Rust’s type resolution deduces that `.into()` must be calling `<io::ErrorKind as Into<io::Error>>::into(io::ErrorKind::Other)` in order to unify the type of the returned expression with the return type of the function. (You can see something similar when you call `.collect()` on the last expression in a function; the type of `collect()` is inferred from the return type of the function, so no type annotation is needed.)